# How to iterate over Multimap in insertion order?

Tags: java, guava

Using the new collections from Google's Guava, http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained

How do I loop over a MultiMap for each key in the order of insertion?

For example

```
multimap = new HashMultiMap<String,String>();
multimap.put("1", "value1");
multimap.put("1", "value2");
multimap.put("1", "value3");

multimap.put("2", "value11");
multimap.put("2", "value22");
multimap.put("2", "value33");

multimap.put("3", "value111");
multimap.put("3", "value222");
multimap.put("3", "value333");
```

On each loop I need

```
"value1", "value11", "value111";
```

then the next loop

```
"value2", "value22", "value222";
```

and so on:

```
"value3", "value33", "value333";
```

Comment: `Hash*` collections do not preserve insertion order.

Comment: looks like i need to use Table not a MultiMap

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not quite sure *what are your needs* (or concrete use case), but I'll try to guess. Other answers suggest using Linked*Multimap or Immutable one, but to get desired output (shown in question) with `Multimap` you will have to create some fancy Map (I'll discuss this later) or for example create three temporary collections holding first, second and third values for each key (they will be in insertion order, if you use one of suggested `Multimap` implementations). Preferably it would be one of `ListMultimaps` as you can iterate over `multimap.keySet()` to get lists with values available by index:

```
final ListMultimap<String,String> multimap = LinkedListMultimap.create();
// put values from question here

final List<Object> firstValues = Lists.newArrayList();
for (final String key: multimap.keySet()) {
  firstValues.add(multimap.get(key).get(0));
}    
System.out.println(firstValues);
// prints [value1, value11, value111]
// similar for multimap.get(key).get(1) and so on
```

but the downside is that you'll have to create three Lists for you example what makes this solution rather unflexible. So maybe it'll be better to put {first,second,third}Values collection to Map>, what brings me to the point:

---

**Maybe you should use [Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) instead?**

Table is designed as *A collection that associates an ordered pair of keys, called a row key and a column key, with a single value* and, what's more important here, has row and column views. I'll use [`ArrayTable`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayTable.html) here:

```
final ArrayTable<String, Integer, Object> table = ArrayTable.create(
    ImmutableList.of("1", "2", "3"), ImmutableList.of(0, 1, 2));

table.put("1", 0, "value1");
table.put("1", 1, "value2");
table.put("1", 2, "value3");

table.put("2", 0, "value11");
table.put("2", 1, "value22");
table.put("2", 2, "value33");

table.put("3", 0, "value111");
table.put("3", 1, "value222");
table.put("3", 2, "value333");

for (final Integer columnKey : table.columnKeyList()) {
  System.out.println(table.column(columnKey).values());
}
// prints:
// [value1, value11, value111]
// [value2, value22, value222]
// [value3, value33, value333]
```

I deliberately used String for row keys which are [1, 2, 3, ...] Integers in fact (like you did in the question) and Integers for column keys starting with 0 ([0, 1, 2, ...]) to show similarity to previous example using List's `get(int)` on multimaps values' collection.

Hope this will be helpful, mostly in determining what you want ;)

P.S. I use `ArrayTable` here, because it has neater way of creating fixed set (universe) of rows / keys values than [`ImmutableTable`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableTable.html), but if mutability isn't required you should use it instead with one change - `ImmutableTable` (and any other Table implementation) doesn't have `columnKeyList()` method, but only `columnKeySet()` which does the same thing, but is slower for `ArrayTable`. And of course [`ImmutableTable.Builder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableTable.Builder.html) or `ImmutableTable.copyOf(Table)` should be used.

Comment: I ended up using table, and iterate over each row, to get a map that represents the entire row.

Answer (score 5):

You can use either [`LinkedListMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedListMultimap.html) or [`LinkedHashMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultimap.html).

The two have very similar behavior; one major difference is that `LinkedListMultimap` allows multiple copies of the same key-value pair to be inserted, whereas `LinkedHashMultimap` allows only one.

See the above-linked Javadoc for much more information.

Comment: I'm not sure about the first point. I tried with a running example and the iteration order using the two multimaps is the same using keys, values, entries and asMap.

Comment: @dawww: Oops, you're right. I must have misread the documentation. I will remove that bullet-point, thanks. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely clear what iteration order you mean, OP...

- `Set<K> keySet()` just returns the keys.
- `Map<K, Collection<V>> asMap()` returns the keys and their associated entries, so you might do `for (Map.Entry<K, Collection<V>> entry : asMap().entrySet())`  to iterate over keys and their associated collections.
- `Collection<Map.Entry<K, V>> entries()` lets you iterate over the entries, but without necessarily grouping them by key.

If you want things in insertion order, use one of the insertion-ordered `Multimap` implementations -- `LinkedHashMultimap`, possibly `LinkedListMultimap`, `ImmutableMultimap`.

Answer (score 2):

For looping over multiple keys:

```
for (Object key : multimap.keys()) { ... }
```

You can also loop over the entries:

```
for (Map.Entry entry : multimap.entries()) { ... }
```

Comment: this is where I am confused, I saw this in a previous question but I wasn't sure how this works? Does it return all values for a specific key or return each value associated with keys? is there an example of this in action?